# Required to Reboot my Android Device Every Week?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, reboot, htc, htc-one

When I got my first Android phone (the rugged HTC Inspire), I was told that I should restart the device every week. The rational, which made sense at the time, was that it's a small computer and every computer needs a soft reset, right? Over time, my phone needed it from continual app crashes but it took forever to do so. Overall, it did help to restart

I've recently upgraded to the HTC One and, from what I can tell, I don't need to restart this thing every week. It's run for a couple weeks on end without problems (one app-hangup what wasn't fixed with a restart) and although my usage isn't intensive, it's getting heavier.

Is it a good idea to restart my Android device after a certain period of time or does it not do anything at all. I'm not so much worried about harming the device but just keeping all of my info current without needing to open up half-dozen apps every time.

EDIT: Sorry if this comes as a duplicate question. I tried looking around for other answers but my particular question related to normal/periodic rebooting not related to a slow-down of the OS or other apps. Most questions regarding rebooting of an Android device revolved around either a slow OS or apps hanging and not necessarily answering my question.